# adding the results of a sorted dictionary in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I have a script which loops over multiple files.
For each file, I count how often a specific combination in the file occurs.

I do this using the following code:

```
with open("%s" %files) as f:
    freqs = {}
    sortedFreqs = []

    # read lines of csv file
    for l in f.readlines():

        # some code here (not added) which fills the mutationList value

    # this dict stores how often which mutation occurs.
    freqs = Counter(mutationList)

    # same list, only sorted.
    sortedFreqs = sorted(freqs.iteritems(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
```

so the freqs variable contains a long list of entries.

example:

```
'FAM123Ap.Y550': 1, 'SMARCB1p.D192': 1, 'CSMD3p.T1137': 3
```

I now want to sort them based on the second value, which are stored in sortedFreqs.

example:

```
'CSMD3p.T1137': 3, 'FAM123Ap.Y550': 1, 'SMARCB1p.D192': 1
```

This is all going fine, however I now want to loop over multiple files, and add all found frequencies together. So if I find the 'CSMD3p.T1137' value 2 more times, I want to store 'CSMD3p.T1137': 5.

```
wanted output:
totalFreqs = 'FAM123Ap.Y550': 1, 'SMARCB1p.D192': 1, 'CSMD3p.T1137': 5, 'TRPM1p.R551': 2
totalFreqsSorted = 'CSMD3p.T1137': 5,'TRPM1p.R551': 2 'FAM123Ap.Y550': 1, 'SMARCB1p.D192': 1'
```

how do I "add" the key values of the dictionaries in python ? (how do I correctly file the values of totalFreqs and totalFreqsSorted)

Comment: `Counter()` objects have a `.most_common()` method that *already* sorts the items for you; no need to sort yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Use **one** `Counter()` object for all counts and update it for each file:

```
freqs = Counter()

for file in files:
    with open(...) as f:
        #

        freqs.update(mutationList)
```

or you can add up counters simply by summing them:

```
total_freqs = Counter()


for file in files:
    with open(...) as f:
        #

        freqs = Counter(mutationList)
        total_freqs += freqs
```

Note that `Counter()` objects *already* provide a reverse-sorted list of frequencies; just use the [`Counter.most_common()` method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common) instead of sorting yourself:

```
sortedFreqs = freqs.most_common()
```

Comment: Yes that would be a good solution, unfortunatelly I want to trace back how often each mutation occurs per file type, which i why i keep a freqs variable for each file.

Comment: @MrFronk: then use the second version. That keeps separate `freqs` objects per file, and sums them together in `total_freqs`. `total_freqs` is a separate `Counter()` for frequencies across all files.